# Hiding status bar while in UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios9, ios-animations

I have implemented a interactive dismissal animation for a controller that is being presented full screen.

The issue is that whenever I try to dismiss it status bar appears[image]

The full screen controller has its `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden` returning `true` so the bar isn't visible when presented.

The presenting view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

Thing's I've tried:

- setting `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden` to `true` and calling `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in `viewWillAppear` in the presenter
- changing the presenters `navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle` properties

Twitter app has the bar hidden when dismissing, so I guess this must be possible

[image: twitter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have achieved the same status bar behavior as in the Twitter app.

The secret is to change the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]`'s `UIWindowLevel` to `UIWindowLevelStatusBar` before the presentation animation and change it back to `UIWindowLevelNormal` (or whatever your window's level was) after the dismissal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside `viewWillAppear()`

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true`

Comment: This works if I set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` in `.plist`, but isn't this method deprecated since iOS9?

Comment: And `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true` does nothing afterwards :(